# pivot wide dataframe with double row heading to deep dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am confident I could muddle through this, and perhaps even land on something elegant, but I'm curious how others would approach this problem:

I would like to take a dataframe like this:

```
| a1   | b1   | c1  |
| ---- | ---- | --- |
| a2   | b2   | c2  |
| ---  | ---  | --- |
| v1   | v2   | v3  |
| ...  | ...  | ... |
| v100 | v101 | v102|
```

And convert to a dataframe like this, where `x*` are custom headers that I can provide a list for:

```
| x1  | x2  | x3   |
| --- | --- | ---- |
| a1  | a2  | v1   |
| ... | ... | ...  |
| a1  | a2  | v100 |
| b1  | b2  | v2   |
| ... | ... | ...  |
| b1  | b2  | v101 |
| c1  | c2  | v3   |
| ... | ... | ...  |
| c1  | c2  | v102 |
```

The context is a CSV import that needs to be pivoted, but has two rows of headers that will become `x1` and `x2` in this situation.

Any tips or suggestions much appreciated!  Again, confident could do this with some elbow grease, but would like to improve my pivoting and index-ing intuition.

**UPDATE**: per comments, here are source and target dataframe examples:

```py
# source dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a1','b1','c1'], data=[['a2','b2','c2'],['v1','v2','v3'],['v100','v101','v102']])

"""
In [14]: df1                                                                                                                                                    
Out[14]: 
     a1    b1    c1
0    a2    b2    c2
1    v1    v2    v3
2  v100  v101  v102
"""

# target dataframe (where "x*" headers will be provided)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1','x2','x3'], data=[['a1','a2','v1'],['a1','a2','v100'],['b1','b2','v2'],['b1','b2','v101'],['c1','c2','v3'],['c1','c2','v102']])

"""
In [16]: df2                                                                                                                                                    
Out[16]: 
   x1  x2    x3
0  a1  a2    v1
1  a1  a2  v100
2  b1  b2    v2
3  b1  b2  v101
4  c1  c2    v3
5  c1  c2  v102
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multi-step reshaping:

```py
(df1.T
 .set_index(0, append=True)
 .rename_axis(['x1', 'x2'])
 .stack()
 .droplevel(-1)
 .reset_index(name='x3')
)
```

Output:

```
   x1  x2    x3
0  a1  a2    v1
1  a1  a2  v100
2  b1  b2    v2
3  b1  b2  v101
4  c1  c2    v3
5  c1  c2  v102
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your initial DataFrame correctly, I can create it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
n = 100
listA = [f'V{x}' for x in range(1,n+1)]
listA.insert(0,("a1"))
listA.insert(1,"a2")
listB = [f'V{x}' for x in range(n+1,2*n+1)]
listB.insert(0,("b1"))
listB.insert(1,"b2")
listC = [f'V{x}' for x in range(2*n+1,3*n+1)]
listC.insert(0,("c1"))
listC.insert(1,"c2")
data = [listA, listB, listC]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

Now you create an empty DataFrame with three columns: "x1", "x2", "x3" :

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame( columns=["x1", "x2", "x3"])
```

And you add the rows in a for loop choosing the location of elements in the original DataFrame:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(n):
        row = [df.iloc[0][i],df.iloc[1][i], df.iloc[j+2][i]]
        newDF.loc[len(newDF.index)] = row
```

Hoping to have been useful to you.

**UPDATE**
According to your Update :
You create a row0 from the columns header :

```
row0 = pd.DataFrame(list(df1.columns)).T
```

You change columns name of row0 and df1 :

```
row0.columns = ["x1","x2","x3"]
df1.columns = ["x1","x2","x3"]
```

You concatenate row0 and df1 in a dnew DataFrame:

```
dnew = pd.concat([row0, df])
```

You create df2 :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["x1", "x2", "x3"])
for i in range(len(dnew.columns)):
    for j in range(len(dnew)-2):
        row = [dnew.iloc[0][i],dnew.iloc[1][i], dnew.iloc[j+2][i]]
        df2.loc[len(df2)] = row
```